# evitar duplicidad al hacer append

Tags: jquery

```js
var mySpan = $('<span class="dropdown"></span>');
$('.header-top-registro>.menu-mobile>li').append(mySpan);
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div class="header-top-registro">
  <div class="menu-mobile" style="right: 0px;">
    <li>
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

su ayuda por favor estoy usando este código para insertar un span dentro de mi html, el problema que tengo cada vez que refresco o hago resize se empieza a duplicar el span, cono evito la duplicidad, gracias

```js
var mySpan = $('<span class="dropdown"></span>');
$('.header-top-registro>.menu-mobile>li').append(mySpan);
```

Comment: Puedes indicar en que evento se ejecuta el script?

Comment: En ready. Lo tengo en un resize y width cuando entra en un tamaño quiero que se añada el span con una clase . Lo hace pero por cada vez que se hace el resize duplica el span con la clase . Espero se entienda gracias

Comment: Debeerias subir esa parte del codigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con la declaración de una variable podrías controlar la ejecución del append. Podrías inicializar la variable con un valor y al momento de ejecutar el append podrías cambiar el valor de la variable, así aseguras que solo se ejecute en determinadas ocaciones o solo una vez.

```
let  numSpan = 0;

    $( window ).resize(function() {

        var mySpan = $('<span class="dropdown"> append </span>');


        if ( $(window).width() < 1200 ){
            if( numSpan == 0 ){
                $('.header-top-registro>.menu-mobile>li').append(mySpan);
                numSpan += 1;
            }
            console.log(numSpan)
        }
    });
```

Espero sea de tu utilidad.

Comment: Hola gracias funciono, solucionado, solo para que nos quede claro o a mi ilustranos, que significa la variable let numSpan = 0; sobre todo let, es un método, propiedad, ? lo explicas gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: En ECMAScript 6 let es el equivalente a var, es más tema de declaración de variables.

Comment: También una manera de hacer funcionar bueno en mi caso vacío todo los hijos nodos del div con empty() posteriormente agrego con append() o prepend() y sus "to"